# MongoDB for .Net simple display data example

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to display data from my MongoDB running on "mongodb://localhost:27017" to a .NET app.

**This is how the Database looks**.

[image]

This example is from the [MongoDB C# Driver page on github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver) and i can't even get pass the compile time errors:
1. I had to remove `await`.
2. The error i am getting now is  under `list`

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' because 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;

namespace MongoTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<Person>("messages");

            collection.InsertOneAsync(new Person { Name = "Jack" });

            var list = collection.Find(x => x.Name == "Jack")
                .ToListAsync();

            foreach (var person in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone share a simple working code snippet, or a link to a working tutorial? This is the second day and i'm still stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either call synchrone methods:  `InsertOne()` and `ToList()`  or wait for results of asynchrone methods:

```
collection.InsertOneAsync(new Person { Name = "Jack" }).Wait();

var list = collection.Find(x => x.Name == "Jack")
            .ToListAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Yes that is a working solution. Now i have a start! Thank you!

Comment: This works in a Console app, but in a Winforms app it doesn't give me any error, also doesn't show anything. I tried this: `foreach (Person p in list)      MessageBox.Show(p.Name);` Do you know why this happens?

Comment: You don't see any message box or do you see an emty messagebox?

Comment: No message box, even in a try catch block, and no error also.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it, are you sure, you are getting any result? have you changed your query? Try first to show the amount of records: MessageBox.Show(list.Count.ToString());

Comment: Yes i have changed something, and now i don't get anything in the console either. It's probably my fault. trying to figure out what is different.

Comment: No, i apologize, it was my fault. Thanks again!

Comment: I finally figured out why it was acting nasty when i was changing test db to my own. I was mapping all the DB fields you see in that picture except for the last one (__v), that is added by mongoose. When i added that too, it all started working :)